# Should the 'configuration' tag be nuked from orbit?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's on 788 questions, but I can't imagine where it'd have a valid use.  Should [configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/configuration) perhaps just be silently nuked in the database and blacklisted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition *everything* that is posted on SF deals with configuration in one way or another. I can't think of a single valid question that can be asked about hardware or software that doesn't fall under the [configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/configuration) umbrella. I'd say nuke it.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration does seem like a meta tag, similar to [security](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/security) or [performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/performance), which describes an aspect of a problem, rather than the specific things the problem involves. Personally, I class it in with the likes of `security` as an allowable meta-tag.

Comment: Based on the general principle of "could this be the only tag on a question and still make sense?", I don't think that [tag:security] is in the same class as [tag:configuration].